# Reading UIWebView TEXT content

Tags: iphone, text, uiwebview

I am interested in reading ONLY the TEXT content of a UIWebView.  How do I do this?  I found lots of help on the web about reading the HTML content but I want ONLY the Text.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get the `.textContent` or `.innerText` of the root node, instead of `.innerHTML`.

```
[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerText;"];
```

(BTW, there is also a *private* property `webView.text`.)